# Remove most of non-alphabetic characters from a string in elisp

Tags: regex, elisp

**I need to remove all non-alphabetic characters and numbers from a string except `-` and `_`**

A popular solution for many languages is to use something like this `[^\\w\\-_]` For some reason this expression, when used with `replace-regexp-in-string`, removes everything.
While `\\W` removes everything but alphabetic characters and numbers as expected:

```lisp
(message (replace-regexp-in-string "\\W" "" "Set AA053 Лыв № foo_bar (设）"))
```

Will output: `SetAA053Лывfoobar设`

*`a-zA-Z0-9`* won't solve my problem because I need to preserve non Latin characters.

## Thanks!

Comment: I think [this post](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8261/how-to-determine-if-the-current-character-is-a-letter) almost answers your question.

Comment: I posted an expanded answer based on the comment I deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIX classes are locale specific, and according to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char-Classes.html),

> `‘[:alnum:]’`
>   This matches any letter or digit. (**At present, for multibyte characters, it matches anything that has word syntax.**)
>   
>   `‘[:alpha:]’`
>   This matches any letter. (**At present, for multibyte characters, it matches anything that has word syntax**.)

That is why to match any character that is not a letter, digit, or underscore/hyphen, you can use a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) solution:

> Typing a caret after the opening square bracket negates the character class. The result is that **the character class matches any character that is not in the character class**.

So, yes, you can use

```
"[^[:alnum:]_-]"
 ^^           ^
```

Or

```
"[^[:alpha:][:digit:]_-]"
```

The hyphen at the end of the character class is treated by the regex engine as a literal hyphen, not any range defining operator.

If you do not care about `_` and want to replace it, remove from the character class.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @wiktorstribiżew I found the right regexp:

`[^[:alnum:]-_]`

*See [Character Classes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char-Classes.html) for details.*